# How can I download a Picaboo photobook?

Tags: download, picaboo

I created a photobook in [Picaboo](http://www.picaboo.com/): is there any way to download it (e.g. as a PDF)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the customer support:

> There is no way to download a Picaboo project or make a .pdf. However
>   you can share the project. Here is some info on sharing:
>
> https://customercare.picaboo.com/hc/en-us/articles/200344714-Can-I-share-my-project-online-with-friends-and-family-